# find number of gnome-terminal tabs currently open by window Id

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, tcsh

How can I find the number of open tabs in my terminal?

I can get the Id of the window by using `xwininfo -name` and giving a name of one of the tabs. For example:

`xwininfo -name "<name of a tab>"` on my machine resulted in:

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0x3000006 "<name of tab>"

...some more info
```

Is there a way to know the number of tabs currently open? I'm using `Ubuntu` with `tcsh` but `bash` solutions are welcome also because they may hint for the solution with `tcsh`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
ps --ppid $(pgrep gnome-terminal)  | grep tcsh | wc -l
```

Comment: Nice one, but the `wc -l` is unneeded. Just do `... grep -c tcsh`. Also, I'd make the pattern more general to match not only `tcsh` but other shells too: `... grep -cE '(ba|tc|z|c)?sh$`.